# How to append to a list using list comprehension and dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have an empty list and a dictionary

```
subject = []
dict = {'1' : 'Test', '2':'Assignments', '3':'Homeworks', etc.}
```

I have another list that is user generated

```
start_prompt = ['1', '2', '5']
```

I want to go through go through the list start_prompt and use it as the key to append the dict values to the empty list subject. This is what I tried doing, but it doesn't work

```
x = [subject.append(dict[i]) for i in start_prompt]
```

Am I missing something really obvious, or is this not the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following, and also check that that key exists in your dictionary.

```
d = {'1' : 'Test', '2':'Assignments', '3':'Homeworks'}
start_prompt = ['1', '2', '5']
subject = [d[i] for i in start_prompt if i in d]

>>> subject
['Test', 'Assignments']
```

P.S. Do not use the type name as your variable! (Do not name your dictionary `dict`)

Comment: Just to add that the reason @nick's solution doesn't work is that calling `subject.append(dict[i])` returns None so it will just be a list of Nones.

Comment: @Hamatti although its side effects should still happen. `subject` should be populated regardless of whether `x` is a list of `None`s

Comment: @Hamatti forgot to include that part, why is that? (I'm aware that's a big piece to leave out)

Comment: @AdamSmith, oh right, I read incorrectly. I thought @nick was trying to populate `x`, not `subject` since he used a list comprehension

Comment: Thanks! This worked. And I know it was just for examples sake, but thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the other answer but for variation

```
d = {'1' : 'Test', '2':'Assignments', '3':'Homeworks'}
start_prompt = ['1', '2', '5']
from operator import itemgetter
itemgetter(*d.viewkeys() & start_prompt)(d)
('Test', 'Assignments')
list(itemgetter(*d.viewkeys() & start_prompt)(d))
['Test', 'Assignments']
```

Not that i recommend it

Comment: Thanks! With the above example, how would I get it to work with both [1, 2, 5] and [1,2,5]? start_prompt is user generated so idk if they will put a space between the commas or not. How can I plan for this?